# Как работает метод Монте-Карло на примере игры крестики-нолики?

Tags: алгоритм

Я не могу понять нескольких вещeй в методе Монте-Карло:
Что делать в самом начале, когда есть только один узел?
Какие поля должны быть у детей узла? (Я думаю, что Ход, кол-во побед, кол-во партий)
Сначала два бота имеют пустые деревья. Они начинают делать случайные ходы, тем самым дополняя дерево. До какого момента это должно продолжаться? 
Или ему всегда нужно делать случайные ходы? 
Может ввести вероятность сделать случайный ход?
Должен ли я в дерево записывать ход противника?

Цель: научить ботов играть в крестики-нолики, используя метод Монте-Карло. (Можно, конечно, перебрать все 9! вариантов, что немного, но это мне нужно для понимания алгоритма)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/330092/